# SSIS: can not run an sql task to update table

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm new to SSIS and SQL Server and what I'm trying to do is to update a table that I have in my database. But it doesn't work with "Execute SQL Task".

Here is what I'm trying to do:

- Create 2 tables if they do not exists (one the final table and the other to store the data that already exists in the database)
- get the data from excel file and my database

  - then I use sort and merge join + derived column + conditional split to get the newest data into the final table and the data that already exists in the database in another table
- afterwards, I'm trying to update the table but here is the problem

Here is the SQL query I use:

```
update
    A
set
    A.[nom technicien] = B.[nom technicien],
    A.[nb intervention] = B.[nb intervention],
    A.[tel] = B.[tel],
    A.[mail] = B.[mail],
    A.[adresse] = B.[adresse],
    A.[id] = B.[id]
from
    fichetech A
inner join fichetechstaged B on
    A.[id] = B.[id];
```

I searched on the internet and haven't found anything that would help me.

Here is a screenshot of the error I get:

[image: error display]

Comment: The SQL In your image does not match the SQL you have posted as text. It looks like you have picked up bit at the end - `CROSS JOIN A` which is probably what is causing the error.

Comment: @GarethD I know but idk why it's that way in the pic there is `CROSS JOIN` but i did not tape it

Comment: @GarethD visual basic is telling me now that the column cannot be updated and it changes my code to `cross join` idk why

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by "telling me now"... did you change something? did the first error go away?

Comment: @jamie no i did not change something, i just looked at the sql query build command and when i try to build, it changes to another sql query

Answer (score 1):

Well i figure it out by myself xD. It took me a while but i did it.
So, what worked for me is: in SQL EXECUTE TASK-> SQL STATEMENT -> BypassPrepare -> False and it worked perfectly.
IDK why it work. If someone can explain it would be great.
Thanks everyone for the help.